# A problem of uniqueness

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, integration, calculus-of-variations

Let $f\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, $a\in(-1,1)$, how i can prove that the following problem:
$$\text{div}(t^a\nabla u)=0,\quad\text{in }\mathbb{R}^n\times(0,\infty),$$
$$ u(x,0)=f(x),\quad\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n,$$
have unique solution such that:
$$ \int_0^\infty\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} y^a |\nabla_{x,y}u|^2\,dx\,dy<\infty? \tag{1}$$
I have to prove only the uniqueness not the existence. The function:
$$ u(x,y)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{y^{1-a}}{y^2+|x-\xi|^2)^{(n+1-a)/2}}f(\xi)\,d\xi,$$
solves the problem and satisfies (1). I have no idea on how to prove the uniqueness.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think $\text{div}(t^a\nabla u)= t^a\Big[\Delta_{x,y}u+\frac at \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\Big]$. So, some sort of maximum modulus argument for harmonic functions should give you uniqueness.

Comment: What is maximum modulus argument for harmonic functions? Can you give some details please?

Comment: Try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_principle first